# how to query RDF with SPARQL enhancing efficient search?

Tags: rdf, sparql

my project is about enabling the user to enter the query and the best results are to be displayed to the user.this is my RDF file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:foaf="http://www.xmlns.com/foaf/0.1">

    <rdf:Description>
    <foaf:name>interview</foaf:name>
    <foaf:url>urlname1</foaf:url>
    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Description>
    <foaf:name>technical</foaf:name>
    <foaf:url>urlname2</foaf:url>
    </rdf:Description>  </rdf:RDF>
```

now if the user enters "technical questions",i coded in the way to take "technical" and "questions" in a array and to dynamically generate a SPARQL query so my query will look like

> String queryString =
>                                     "PREFIX rdf: http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns# " +
>                                     "PREFIX foaf: http://www.xmlns.com/foaf/0.1 " +
>                                       "SELECT   ?url WHERE { ?a foaf:name ?name FILTER regex(?name,'"+ values[i]+"') ?a foaf:url
>   ?url.}";

here values[i] is the array defined for "technical" and "questions".so this gives me an output as

> ```
> ------------- 
> | url       |
> ============= 
> | "urlname2"|
> -------------
> ```
>
> and when the user enters "interview questions" the result would be
>
> ```
> ------------- 
> | url       |
> ============= 
> | "urlname1"|
> -------------
> ```

But if the user enters "technical interview questions" it gives me both as o/p like

> ```
>  ------------- 
>  | url       |
>  ============= 
>  | "urlname2"|
>  -------------
>  ------------- 
>  | url       |
>  ============= 
>  | "urlname1"|
>  -------------
> ```

but the o/p which i should get is only the first table that gives me url to prepare for technical questions(urlname2).can you please tell me how to alter my query/RDF format to get the desired o/p ? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The data doesn't mean what you think it does.

You have one object, with two different foaf:names.

Try converting the RDF/XML into Turtle or NTriples to get a clearer view of the data RDF/XML is very confusing.

Comment: I have edited my question sir.Thank you for your kind response.Please help me to solve this problem sir.